# Using listbox, how to find that exact object?

Tags: c#, listbox

I think this is a somewhat easy answer but Im not able to understand how to do it.

I have an object (lets call it A) with a list of other objects (for example places)
So Im creating a Webapp and in that page I have a listbox of places (Im using the name of the places (string) as a unique id). The question is when I select an item from that list, how do I find that item in the list of places?

for example:

page.aspx:

```
 <p style="margin-left: 40px">
    Select place:</p>
<p style="margin-left: 40px">
    <asp:ListBox ID="listplace" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
</p>
```

page.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            listplace.DataSource = A.listOfPlaces;
            listplace.DataBind();
        }
     }
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer this; there's all sorts of technologies that you could be using to display A in your web application.  In what way are you showing A, and how are you getting it from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this can help you:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBox_42581647
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Doit();
        }

        private void Doit()
        {
            ListBox lb = new ListBox();//create a listbox
            lb.Items.Add(new aPlace { placename = "TheBar", placeCoolFactor = "booze" });//add something to the listbox
            lb.Items.Add(new aPlace { placename = "TheHouse", placeCoolFactor = "bowl"});//add something to the listbox
            lb.Items.Add(new aPlace { placename = "ThePark", placeCoolFactor = "dogs" });//add something to the listbox

            lb.SelectedItem = lb.Items[1];//lets fake a selection

            var theSelectedPlace = lb.SelectedItem;//the actual item selected
            var theSelectedPlaceName = ((aPlace)lb.SelectedItem).placename;//the selected item place name
            var theSelectedPlaceCoolFactor = ((aPlace)lb.SelectedItem).placeCoolFactor;//the selected item place cool factor


            //now I'll create your (lets call it A)
            List<aPlace> parallelList = new List<aPlace>();//lets call it A
            parallelList.Add((aPlace)lb.Items[0]);//This list contains the same items your ListBox contains
            parallelList.Add((aPlace)lb.Items[1]);//This list contains the same items your ListBox contains
            parallelList.Add((aPlace)lb.Items[2]);//This list contains the same items your ListBox contains

            //find the selected by matching the selected Placename
            aPlace theChosenPlace = parallelList.Where(p => p.placename == theSelectedPlaceName).FirstOrDefault();
            //find the selected by matching the actual item
            aPlace theChosenPlace2 = parallelList.Where(p => p == theSelectedPlace).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }

    public class aPlace
    {
        public string placename { get; set; }
        public string placeCoolFactor { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
string currPlace = listplace.SelectedItem.ToString();
string place = A.listOfPlaces.Where
    (x => x.Contains(currPlace)).FirstOrDefault();
```